# How to load an image in matlab from java

Tags: java, matlab

Basically I am trying to create a little program that will allow me to make calls in matlab from a jave GUI

It's mainly going to be used for image manipulation and deblurring but I am struggling to find a way that will effectively give me full matlab control from the java end

I am hoping to have it work like so:

```
{
    //create matlab execution call
    String loadImage = " image1 = imread ('imageOnComputer.jpg'); ";

    //send instruction to matlab and save the path to it so java can 
    //use the newly created variable
    resultingVariablePath = java.sendInstructionToMatlab(loadImage);

    //display on the screen
    java.displayImage(resultingVariablePath);
}
```

Basically I am just trying to find out if there is a plugin for matlab (or some java package) that will grant you (pretty much) full control over matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished easily by using [matlabcontrol](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com). For your case the best method to call would be MatlabProxy's [returningEval](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxy.html#returningEval%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [post](http://shatterednirvana.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/howto-call-matlab-from-java-kinda/) that talks of it

Comment: Would make a great comment (if some context were added to the link).